# Question relates to "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in FpdiTrait.php"

Tags: fpdf, fpdi

I see by all the threads that this issue has arisen many times in differing environments and in different forms.  Most answers I have seen suggest changing the PHP version.  Here's my puzzler.  My client has a website that is running on PHP5.6.  I have an installation running from his root directory that is working perfectly.  My use of `$pdf = new fpdi();` in that code works perfectly.

Okay ... I have put test code one level down, and the url for it simply calls for the **root level/my sublevel/mycode.php**.  In this, the php file is exactly the same, just running in a different folder (So, I should be under the host's same PHP setup).  But, I get the error,

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home4/ldhrnhb9/public_html/musanizer/RNHB-MusicCamp-2019/src/FpdiTrait.php on line 103
```

Any ideas that do not involve a php version change?  Remember, the same exact code is running under PHP5.6 just one folder level up.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to add that the source code in the new sub level for fpdi() is located (relatively) just as it is in the working code.  It cannot be a path issue

Comment: This error is only possible if the file is parsed by a PHP version < 5.6. What is the `phpversion()` output in `mycode.php`?

Comment: HMMMM  ... good call. My log reads 2019-01-25 06:36:51 5.4.45  ... the 5.4.45 being a return of phpversion().  That just blew my understanding of PHP.  Since the hosted service is running PHP 5.6??

Comment: I believe that is going to solve things for me.  I was going by the word of my client's host admin that everything was on PHP5.6 ... He was wrong ... has cost me hours of frustration and recoding, etc.  Lesson learned: never take someone else's word for that kind of critical info ... test it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP version must be at least 5.6 as you can read in composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
    "ext-zlib": "*"
},
```